# HugeTLB huge pages and IO mapping: Why does it waste memory?

Tags: linux-kernel, huge-pages

Using `hugepages=` kernel parameter at boot or using `echo 1024 > /proc/sys/vm/nr_hugepages` allocates memory.

```
# cat /proc/meminfo
MemTotal:       32565364 kB
MemFree:        30179992 kB
MemAvailable:   30820684 kB
HugePages_Total:       0
HugePages_Free:        0
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
Hugetlb:               0 kB


# echo 1024 > /proc/sys/vm/nr_hugepages

# cat /proc/meminfo
MemTotal:       32565364 kB
MemFree:        28082216 kB
MemAvailable:   28723824 kB
HugePages_Total:    1024
HugePages_Free:     1024
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
Hugetlb:         2097152 kB
```

It allocates 2GB (1024 Hugepages x 2MB) from 30GB to 28GB (`MemFree`).

#### Why? How can I remove this behavior?

I only want to reserve the TLB entries, not the actual physical memory. I will never allocate such huge pages since I will only use them to mmap IO memory.

**This behavior wastes 2GB of my physical memory.**

Comment: What is your question? If you don’t want kernel to use THP, don’t enable them. I think you simply misinterpreted the output of that file. And allocation indeed happened, but for the internal kernel structures (yes, page tables). As a result you got into wrong conclusions.

Comment: Is that related to THP? Since it's for IO mapping, I don't use Transparent HP. I don't understand why enabling huge pages reduces the free/available memory. Using huge pages has nothing to do with allocating memory, it's just a TLB entry. Unless I'm missing something.

Comment: Possibly you may find the information among the LWN articles on the topic: https://lwn.net/Kernel/Index/#Huge_pages.

Comment: I'll read, thank you!